# Qt QML - Action Shortcut Doesn't Work in QML When Combining Qt Widgets and QML with QWidget::createWindowContainer()

Tags: qt, widget, qml

I started the example to create a Qt GUI application with a UI class derived from QMainWindow and a Qt Designer form. 
In the implementation of the UI class in mainwindow.cpp, I created a QQuickView and then call QWidget::createWindowContainer(), passing in the view and the parent widget. This returns a QWidget that we can add to the UI layout. Shown below is the code in mainwindow.cpp.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Tab Dialog"));

    _qmlView        = new QQuickView();
    _qmlView->setSurfaceType(QSurface::OpenGLSurface);
    _qmlView->setSource(QUrl("TMainView.qml"));
    _qmlView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    _qmlWidget      = QWidget::createWindowContainer(_qmlView);

    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(_qmlWidget);
}
```

I created a simple QML file which displays a rectangle and when user click right mouse button the Menu will be appeared.

```
Rectangle {
    id: main
    width: 600
    height: 300

    Rectangle{

        Menu {
            id: menu
            title: "Edit";

            MenuSeparator { }

            MenuItem { action: copyAction; shortcut: StandardKey.Copy }
            MenuItem { action: pasteAction }
            MenuItem { action: selectAllAction }

            MenuSeparator { }
            MenuItem { action: deleteAction }
            MenuItem { text: "Delete all" }

            MenuSeparator { }
            MenuItem { text: "Auto arrange" }

            }
    }

    Action {
            id: copyAction
            text: "&Copy"
            shortcut: StandardKey.Copy
            iconName: "edit-copy"
            onTriggered: console.log("Ctrl+C is pressed")
        }

    Action {
            id: pasteAction
            text: "&Paste"
            shortcut: StandardKey.Paste
            iconName: "edit-paste"
            onTriggered: console.log("Ctrl+V is pressed")
        }

    Action {
            id:selectAllAction
            text: "&SellectAll"
            shortcut: StandardKey.SelectAll
            iconName: "edit-selectAll"
            onTriggered: console.log("Ctrl+A is pressed")
        }

    Action {
            id: deleteAction
            text: "&Delete"
            shortcut: StandardKey.Delete
            iconName: "edit-delete"
            onTriggered: console.log("Delete is pressed")
        }

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill : parent;
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

        onClicked: {
            if(mouse.button === Qt.RightButton){
                menu.popup();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my question is when I click right mouse button, shortcut doesn't work after that but then I minimize the windows and then maximize shortcut will be activated again. Whenever I click right mouse button, shortcut will be disable. WHY?

Comment: I ask my question in Qt forum (https://forum.qt.io/topic/60707/action-shortcut-doesn-t-work-in-qml-when-combining-qt-widgets-and-qml-with-qwidget-createwindowcontainer/2), someone suggested me to use QQuickWidget instead, But unfortunately the keyboard shortcuts don't trigger at all in QQuickWidget.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal testcase and open a bug report then...

Comment: The issues had been closed after Qt 5.9. But I still ran into the same issue in 5.10.1.